# Problems installing PyCurl on python2.7.0+

Tags: python, pycurl, ubuntu-10.10

pycurl installs fine on python2.6 but i get the following error when I try to install in on 2.7 via easy_install on maverick

```
$ sudo easy_install pycurl
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
Searching for pycurl
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/
Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/
Best match: pycurl 7.19.0
Downloading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Processing pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Running pycurl-7.19.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-PFzxzf/pycurl-7.19.0/egg-dist-tmp-oAFjdV
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.21.0)
src/pycurl.c:42: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Is 2.7 not compatible with pycurl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

This installs the Python development package that is required and fixes the problem of the missing header file.

(Please read the comment by Corey)

Comment: note that if 2.7 is not your default Python, you will want to do "sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev" instead.